# Arithmetics in a regex in a lisp function

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I want to replace all hard column widths in several LaTeX-documents, e.g. replace `{90mm}` by `{0.75\textwidth}`. I already found out that you can use `\,` and `#1` to so arithmetics on captured groups, like e.g. [here](http://www.anoopjohnson.com/2013/03/arithmetic-in-emacs-regular-expression-search-and-replace/). But I can't get it to work in a lisp function. I tried several things to no avail, and now would like if this is possible at all, and if yes, how.

Here's something that I came up with that doesn't work:

```
(defun colum-width-relative ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (save-excursion 
    (query-replace-regexp 
     "{\\([0-9]+\\)mm}"
     (concat "{0." \,(/ (* #1 100) 120) "\\\\textwidth}"))))
```

Comment: `query-replace-regexp` is intended for interactive use, the way to do this is to use `re-search-forward` in a loop, based on `(match-string 1)` make a decision about the new value of text width, and then use `replace-match` to substitute it with the new value.

Comment: @wvxvw: Would you care to formulate this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example. See if I understood the problem correctly.

```
(defun colum-width-relative ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (save-excursion
    (while (re-search-forward "{\\([0-9]+\\)mm}" nil t)
      (replace-match
       (format "{%0.2f\\\\textwidth}"
               (/ (string-to-number (match-string 1)) 120.0))))))
```

---

Here's an extended version:

```
(defun colum-width-relative (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (cl-labels ((replacer
               (&rest _)
               (format "{%0.2f\\\\textwidth}"
                       (/ (string-to-number (match-string 1)) 120.0))))
    (let ((re "{\\([0-9]+\\)mm}"))
      (save-excursion
        (if arg
            (perform-replace re (list #'replacer) t t nil)
          (while (re-search-forward re nil t)
            (replace-match (replacer))))))))
```

If you call the extended version with prefix argument, i.e. <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd>`column-width-relative` it will query you before replacing every instance matching regular expression.

Comment: Works great, but as a paranoid person I don't like to just replace stuff without double checking it. Is there a kind of `query-replace-match` that lets me decide for each case individually (pressing `y` or `n`)?

Comment: @Shylock I've added a version which will query before replacing.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This saves me quite a bit of time. Once I reach 15 points you'll also feel the gratitude in form of a counted upvote :D